# How can I log the moment a transformation is called on a DataFrame?

Tags: logging, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I'm building an ML Pipeline which extract features from a DataFrame and I'd like it to behave like the following :

- Log "Extracting feature 1"
- Extract feature 1
- Log "Extracting feature 2"
- Extract feature 2
- ...
- Log "Extracting feature n"
- Extract feature n

The things is, transformations being lazy, I end up with the following :

- Log "Extracting feature 1"
- Log "Extracting feature 2"
- Log "Extracting feature n"
- Extract feature 1
- Extract feature 2
- ...
- Extract feature n

My transform method looks a bit like that :

```
override def transform(dataset: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
   require(featuresToExtract.size > 0, "You must provide at least one feature to extract to use this FeatureExtractorTransformer")

   var joinedDataFrame = extract(dataset, featuresToExtract head)

   for (featureToExtract <- featuresToExtract.tail) {
     // LOGGING HERE THAT I WANT CALLED JUST BEFORE THE CORRESPONDING ACTION
     joinedDataFrame = joinedDataFrame.join(extract(dataset, featureToExtract), joinOn, "outer")
   }
   joinedDataFrame
}
```

So any idea on how to proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: You could add an action after each transformation (e.g. count). That will circumvent lazy evaluation. I would advise against that though as it will kill most optimizations Spark can do.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'd like to avoid. I know about this solution (e.g take(1)) but it feels very wrong. I would have liked something like the possibility to attach a log somewhere ...